# ARKit dae model position

Tags: ios, scenekit, ios11, augmented-reality, arkit

I create SCNNode with .dae model.

```
   let node = SCNNode()  
   let scene = SCNScene(named: "scene.scnassets/scene.dae")! 
   for child in scene.rootNode.childNodes
   {
       node.addChildNode(child)
   }
```

Then add simbTransform and add node to the ar scene

```
   var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
   translation.columns.3.z = -1
   node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
   self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

When I move camera node is attached to it. So i can't walk around node or walk up closer.

But when I do something like that, it work as I expected.

```
  let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, length: 0.5, chamferRadius: 0)) 
  var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
  translation.columns.3.z = -1
  node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
  self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

So how can I attach node with .dae model to specify position and not the camera.

Answer (score 0):

In which method you are doing this code?
 
`var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
   translation.columns.3.z = -1
   node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
   self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)`

If you do this in update method of AR session then it is logical because you change transform of the object every time camera moves. 
Make sure you call this only once - during the scene setup.